# Are there different kinds of killing?

Tags: dharma

Scriptures say "vadha" for the killing of bad entities.

There is capital punishment, homicide, slaughtering animals for sacrifice etc.

Are there different terms for all these forms of killing and different dharmic rules concerning them?

Comment: mrityudanda/pranadanda, hatya, pashu-bali?